# How to change the length of time a tooltip stays open in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

So as many of you know [XKCD](http://www.xkcd.com/) uses the tooltip to provide some *extra* funny information about the last comic. However sometimes the tooltips are long and while reading them it will go away. I then have to move my mouse back over the image to get the tooltip. When I'm using Ubuntu the tooltip stays open as long as I have my mouse over the image. How can I get this effect in Chrome?

Comment: what browser(s)?

Comment: Woops! Google Chrome. I retaged my question to clarify.

Comment: its not a proper solution but you could always rightclick and view the properties of the image

Comment: @The Journeyman Geek: Thanks! Still it would be nice if I didn't have too.

Comment: I removed the tag `windows-7` because this is independent os (Windows) OS.

Comment: @TorbenGundtofte-Bruun Chrome 79.0.3945.88 (Officiële build) (64-bits) works as desired on Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 7):

I know you tagged this question for Google Chrome, but for those who come by looking, Firefox 3.6 *finally* resolved this "bug" by removing the tooltip timeout - [Bug 395668](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=395668).

Reading [XKCD](http://www.xkcd.com) title text will no longer be a race against the clock!

Comment: How did you know?!